# Intel hd graphics 4000 overheating under Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, intel-graphics, proprietary-drivers

I have just installed Debian Jessie xfce 4.10 on a laptop with Intel hd graphics 4000 and it overheats even while watching videos, causing sudden shutdown of the system. While running Windows everything works well, so I think the problem is caused by default Debian's graphic driver. 
I can't find a proper one for Debian. Where can I get it and how to reinstall it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You could try enabling the `backports` repository, and then installing a `linux-image-amd64` kernel from the 4.X series. You'll probably also need to get `firmware-linux-nonfree`from there.

Once/If the backports repository is enabled, you can:

`apt-get install -t jessie-backports linux-image-amd64 firmware-linux-nonfree`

[Backports-Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports), and [further instructions](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)